# how to get Repeater's delegate data in c++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, repeater

In QML like follow:

```
Repeater {
    objectName: "main_layer_wnd"
    id: layer_show_list
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: delegateLayerModel
    delegate: delegateLayerShow
}

Component {
    id: delegateLayerShow
    LayerItemWndView {
        objectName: "delegateLayerShowItem"
    }
}
```

and in c++ code like follow:

```
mpMainLayerWnd = mpWnd->findChild<QQuickItem*>("main_layer_wnd");
QQuickItem* content = mpMainLayerWnd->property("contentItem").value<QQuickItem*>();
QList<QQuickItem*> list = content->childItems();
```

when run this code: 
  content->childItems(); 
Here will throw an exception, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first something regarding your title: I have no idea what you consider the *delegate data* but maybe we will still find a satisfying answer.

For your error, I would say, it is expected. Let's break down your code into smaller parts:

```
mpMainLayerWnd = mpWnd->findChild<QQuickItem*>("main_layer_wnd"); // 1
QVariant prop = mpMainLayerWnd->property("contentItem")           // 2
QQuickItem* content = prop.value<QQuickItem*>();                  // 3
QList<QQuickItem*> list = content->childItems();                  // 4
```

1. You find the child. This should be ok, and you'll have a `QQuickItem*` in mpMainLayerWnd
2. You try to read the property `contentItem` that does not exist. You get an empty `QVariant`.
3. You try to convert the content of the empty `QVariant` to a `QQuickItem*`, which will result in `nullptr`
4. You try to access a method of a `nullptr`.

=> There is no method `childItems()` on a `nullptr`

---

What is unclear to my, why you expect to have `contentItem` in a `Repeater`, since non such is documented in `QObject`, `QQuickItem` nor in `Repeater`.

Most likely you mix up a `default property` with `contentItem`. The default property is the property to which QML automatically assigns everything you create within the `{ }` of an object, without assigning it to some other property.

```
Item {
    id: rootItem
    Item { // this will go to the rootItems default property (data)
    }
}
```

---

The next thing is what I was wondering in the beginning: what is the delegate data you try to access? Do you want to get the Component? Then you can read the property `delegate` of the `Repeater`.

You want to get the instances of the `delegate`? Here I am a bit lost. I think they are in the `children()` of the `Repeater`, and in the `childItem()` of the `Repeater`s parent.

Comment: thank you.I want to get the instances of the delegate, they are in the childItem() of the Repeaters parent.